# How to pass same httpServletRequest object to different domain Or server in java

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, httprequest, http-redirect

Actually, I have two servers(as web services) where one server say S1 receives post request which has encrypted data in body and plain data in header. Now I want to extract plain data from request header for processing in S1(Which i am able to do it) but next is I want to send same httpServletRequest object to another server say S2 as POST request.

I have explored sendRedirect but in that case it lost the request and response objects.

Any other options Or How I could achieve this in Java servlet?

I know this is design issue but client don't want to change design.

Comment: Sounds like you need to implement a web service client for S2 in S1, don't you think so?

Comment: Normally, redirecting between different domains is restricted, due to security issues. could you establish a "tunnel": the first receives, resend to the second, receive the response, re-send the response ?

Comment: Why do you want to send the `HttpServletRequest` object rather than its content (i.e. parameters and/or body) ?

Comment: The httpServletRequest object has life within a Servlet Container (or say server), which is created from HTTP request recieved by Servlet Container. Simply passing on any Httpxxxxx objects between servers is not possible.

Comment: @Gael, Yes that is one option I am considering if there is no better option.