# Passing HttpServletRequest to another API controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlets, spring-rest

I have a controller that receives `HttpServletRequest` with body `form-data` with some `key-value`

I want to pass this `HttpServletRequest` to another API. That another API controller receives `HttpServletRequest`

So far, I've tried this in my service class.

```
public void saveApi(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(request.getCode());
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();         
    HttpServletRequest result = restTemplate.postForObject( "http:localhost:8080/save", request, HttpServletRequest .class);
}
```

The result is the other API `java.lang.NullPointerException: null`, other API didn't receive my post.

How to do that? Is it possible?

Another service, for example: `GET` method, I use the `RestTemplate` to call to another API with some parameter, it succeeds.

**UPDATE**

the answer is:

```
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

MultiValueMap<String, Object> form = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
form.add("name", request.getParameter("name"));
form.add("blabla", request.getParameter("blabla"));
form.add("blabla", request.getParameter("blabla"));

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(form, httpHeaders);
restTemplate.postForEntity("http:localhost:8080/save", requestEntity, String.class);
```

Comment: I doubt that you can pass the request that way. Can you please post the stack trace?

Comment: see the comments here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34133561/how-to-pass-same-httpservletrequest-object-to-different-domain-or-server-in-java

Comment: @SimonMartinelli hi sir, im building a api for bridge from front end to another api in backend. the api didnt receive my servlet request, it says null pointer. but when i use postman request direct to that api it success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`RestTemplate::postForObject`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#postForObject-java.net.URI-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-) and this class in general you have to pass the correct `request` object:

> The request parameter can be a HttpEntity in order to add additional HTTP headers to the request, that is [`HttpEntity`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpEntity.html) with body and headers.

Note the `HttpServletRequest` extends `ServletRequest`.

1. Extract body using either [`ServletRequest::getInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getInputStream()) or [`ServletRequest::getReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getReader()). In case of `multipart/form-data` use [`HttpServletRequest::getParts`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts())
2. Serialize the bytes of body to an object that is required for `POST http:localhost:8080/save`.
3. Use the object and create [`new HttpEntity(T body)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpEntity.html#HttpEntity-T-).
4. Pass it as `request` inside the [`RestTemplate::postForObject`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#postForObject-java.net.URI-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-) method.

The exact steps might differ regarding what data you need, the point is you cannot pass `HttpServletRequest` directly but use an instance of `HttpEntity`.

Comment: it works. but i dont use the .getparts() method. thank you very much for the answer